# Should I be wearing socks with the Nike Hyperfeel?

Tags: running

I bought a pair of Nike Hyperfeel shoes and they are amazing to run in, but I now have huge blisters on my both of my ankles and a small one on the ball of my left foot.

I got the impression that the point of these shoes was that you didn't need socks, am I wrong should I have worn socks?

The irritating thing is I think the blisters are from the periods I was walking between intervals rather than when I was running in the shoes as I toe strike rather than heel strike and the blisters only hurt when I was walking.

This isn't my first pair of minimalist shoes I previously had a pair of Kinvara 4s but I wore socks with them.

Comment: Blisters are a reaction to a new stimulus/irritation. They will go away over time and develop calluses.

Comment: Yes but should I be wearing socks with these shoes or not? I accept the blisters will heal and I'll probably alternate between the Kinvara and the Hyperfeel until I've worked up enough callus to be able to mostly use the Hyperfeel.

Comment: I already voted to close your question as primarily opinion based. Do what feels best for you.

Comment: Is it opinion based? I genuinely want to know whether you are SUPPOSED TO wear socks with these shoes or whether they are designed to not require socks. I can rephrase the question to that effect if that would help.

Comment: I don't know of any shoe model/brand that specifically says you should or should not wear socks. (I've been running since 1983 including x-country HS and college). That's why I marked it as opinion, I always wear socks, but I know others that never wear socks. YMMV.

Comment: Yes but given the fact that the Nike Flyknit range is supposed to "fit like a sock" is the idea that even people who would normally wear socks when running can/should forgo them or is it a case of if you normally wear socks then you should wear sock with these shoes. As I said in the question I wear socks with my Kinvaras, and got the impression that these shoes were designed so you didn't wear socks with them.

Comment: That isn't a "fact", it's a marketing slogan. You want my opinion? Wear socks. There is nothing on the Nike site indicating yes or no, which means they leave it up to the end user. Hence, it's personal preference.

Comment: Not to argue semantics but if Nike's marketing bods say it fits like a sock then it is supposed to fit like a sock regardless of whether it does or doesn't. I get your point though in that it may be up to user preference, which is a third option to two I provided. I guess the question could have been reworded as Should the Nike Hyperfeel be worn with or without socks or is it a matter of user preference. Because I can't find any text which says either way but all the marketing photos seem to be sockless.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13498/discussion-between-johnp-and-omar-kooheji)

Comment: I'd even argue that this question is off topic.  Even though running is related to fitness, this is more of a product specific question and not a fitness question.

Comment: If there were a running SE site I would have asked there. This seemed like the most likely candidate. I apologise if I picked the wrong site.

Comment: This is the most likely site, but the topic wouldn't really fit on any SE site, as it's either a personal opinion or a shopping recommendation question.

Comment: @JohnP Agreed.  Omar, just because this site may be the best fit or better than all of the other sites, does not mean that it should be asked here.  Some questions are out of scope for every site.  That's also why you can make your own on area51.stackexchange.com.  Sorry, just because the square peg fits in the round hole, it doesn't imply that it belong there.

Comment: "Gear and gadgets used during exercise" are on-topic for this site. I think this would include running shoes. However, you might rephrase this question as "How can I avoid getting blisters with my Nike Hyperfeel shoes?" and define how you are using the product to come up with that result. This way you are presenting the problem that you have with the gear itself, and not asking a question which could be considered far more "opinion-based." There may still be a lot of YMMV in the answers that could be provided, but you'll get some good ideas as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Nike Hyperfeel Shoes are intended to offer a light, barefoot feel. However, if they are causing blisters for the user then it would be advised to use a low no-show sock with them to prevent the blisters.

> If you’re looking for a completely unique barefoot feel
>   experience check out the Nike Free 1.0 Cross Bionic

[Here](http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/c/womens-training/free-hyperfeel-cross-elite/) is a newer shoe that may fill your need.